# Proper syntax for performing an intersection with geography

Tags: polygon, intersection, wkt

So, I am doing homework and I am unable to figure this step out.

1. Right-click the tables you just created, click *Design*, then add a new column in it, which is called *GEOG*, datatype is *geography*. Save the changes to your tables.
2. Fill the *GEOG column* with *WKT column* converted to `Line`/`Polygon` data.
3. For *counties table* build a new `UPDATE` query, convert *WKT* to `Polygon` and save it into *GEOG column*.

> Table 1 is *brazosStreet* and table 2 is *counties*.
>
> Table1 WKT is `LINESTRING`, and Table2 is `POLYGON`.

I am stuck on the Table2 `Polygon` step.

Validate the data and perform an intersection:

```
Geog.MakeValid();
Geog.STIntersects(Geog1) = 1;
```

The Validation:

```
Update [dbo].[Counties]
set Geog = Geog.MakeValid()
```

Perform the Selection:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[counties]
WHERE Geog.STIntersects(geography::STLineFromText(‘LINESTRING(-98.144094 31.915186, -93.914357 30.977930)’, 4326);
```

---

**No matter what I type for the *"Perform the selection"* section, I get an error. I tried `STPolyFromText` and I tried deleting and starting over 3 times.**

The only thing I can think of is that I skip over this section because I cannot get it to work:

Validate the data and perform an intersection

```
Geog.MakeValid();
Geog.STIntersects(Geog1) = 1;
```

The way I read that was as on overview of what is to come.  Since it looks like `Geog.MakeValid();` is part of the validation stage and `Geog.STIntersects(Geog1) = 1;` looks like part of the perform the selection stage.

**Why is my syntax not working properly?** I am unsure what SQL language exactly this is. Please let me know if I need to explain this situation more. Thanks for the help in advance!

```
UPDATE [dbo].[brazosStreets] 
SET
[Geog] = geography::STLineFromText([WKT],4326);
UPDATE [dbo].[counties]
SET Geog = Geog.MakeValid;
select *
from [dbo].[counties] c
where c.STIntersect(geography::STLineFromText(‘LINESTRING(-98.144097 
31.915186, -93.914357 30.977930)’,4326))=1;
```

I get error 102 when I try to run this..  Error with the 'single quote' placement involving a non-boolean operator

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I have edited your post to fix formatting issues and make your question more clear. If you're unhappy with any of the changes, feel free to edit your question again.

Comment: I solved it!!  I was importing my code from Word processor with single quotes ' not being the proper ones!!

Comment: Cool! Please post an answer describing how you solved the problem and accept your own answer. This will help future users with similar issues.